# Position of views in emulator is different from the layout

Tags: java, android

The position of widgets in my emulator is changing even though I change the margins it's still in different positions.

How can I fix it? My XML code doesn't seem to match with the UI, the other layouts seem to be okay and this is the only layout I have a problem with.

Thanks for your help :)

Here is my xml code:

```
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="@drawable/bg"
tools:context=".LoadingScreen"
tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="25dp">


<TextView
    android:id="@+id/scissors"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginBottom="172dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="30dp"
    android:fontFamily="@font/bungee_inline"
    android:text="@string/scissors"
    android:textColor="@color/colorPrimary"
    android:textSize="60sp"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/rock"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginBottom="17dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="19dp"
    android:fontFamily="@font/bungee_inline"
    android:text="@string/rock"
    android:textColor="@color/colorPrimaryDark"
    android:textSize="60sp"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/paper"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@+id/paper" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/paper"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginBottom="49dp"
    android:fontFamily="@font/bungee_inline"
    android:text="@string/paper"
    android:textColor="@android:color/holo_red_light"
    android:textSize="60sp"
    [![enter image description here][1]][1]app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/scissors"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView2"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginBottom="59dp"
    android:text="@string/press_start"
    android:textColor="@color/colorPrimary"
    android:textSize="20sp"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent" />

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

and here is my layout and emulator images:
[image][image]

Comment: Your images never came through, but this sounds like maybe it doesn't have anything directly to do with the emulator; for all you know you'd have the same layout problem on a real phone/tablet.  So, it is just a layout problem.

Comment: use match parent width in both textview and gravity centre

Comment: @bugfreerammohan still not working.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

there is only little problem in your layout, which is you have used margin properties in inconsistent way. For Ex, layout_marginRight="19dp" will need some more space than some other device according to their device configurations and size.
so, you should have to use your layout like below,

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="#001235">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:text="ROCK"
        android:textColor="@android:color/white"
        android:textSize="40sp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/textView2"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.5"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:text="PAPER"
        android:textColor="@android:color/white"
        android:textSize="40sp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/textView3"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.5"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/textView" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView3"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:text="SCISSOR"
        android:textColor="@android:color/white"
        android:textSize="40sp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/textView4"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.5"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/textView2" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView4"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:text="<<Press to Start>>"
        android:textColor="@android:color/white"
        android:textSize="20sp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.5"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/textView3" />
</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

this will work nearly equal in almost all devices. always try to provide the attributes value dynamic instead of static as much as it is possible

Comment: Should I manually write the code? because I only used infer constraints in my activites.

Comment: No, you don't have to manually write code. you just need to figure out the How the Layout Editor works for Constraint Layout. So, Practice ConstraintLayout more and more form official Documentation to be good at it. you Should Refer this ConstraintLayout Tutorial from codeLab : https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/constraint-layout

Answer (score 1):

Your constraints are bad, here You have some example for Your view how to set them:

```
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    >

  <TextView
      android:id="@+id/rock"
      android:layout_width="wrap_content"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      android:text="rock"
      app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/paper"
      app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
      app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
      app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
      app:layout_constraintVertical_chainStyle="packed"
      />

  <TextView
      android:id="@+id/paper"
      android:layout_width="wrap_content"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      android:text="paper"
      android:textColor="@android:color/holo_red_light"
      app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/scissors"
      app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
      app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
      app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/rock"
      app:layout_constraintVertical_chainStyle="packed"
      />

  <TextView
      android:id="@+id/scissors"
      android:layout_width="wrap_content"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      android:text="scisors"
      app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/textView2"
      app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
      app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
      app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/paper"
      app:layout_constraintVertical_chainStyle="packed"
      />

  <TextView
      android:id="@+id/textView2"
      android:layout_width="wrap_content"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      android:layout_marginBottom="60dp"
      android:text="press_start"
      app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
      app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
      app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
      />

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

Then add some margins to fit your layout